# Show that the product converge

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

I have never worked with infinite products before, so I have no idea how to do this. So a hint would be much appreciated.

1. show that the product $\prod (1+\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}})$ diverges
2. let $e_k = 0$ if $k$ is odd and $1$ otherwise. let $b_k = \frac{e_k}{k} + \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$. show that the product $\prod (1+b_k)$ converges.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: its from real mathematical analysis by pugh

Comment: Aden: Thank you.  Could you please give a more specific reference (page, exercise number perhaps)?  I think I found it: Exercise 63 on page 198, Chapter 3.

Comment: Naive remark: for 1., I guess the product is for $k\geq 2$, otherwise it is $0$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer yeah that's the question

Comment: @julien yep but i think that should be fairly obvious

Comment: Well it would definitely be obvious if you stated it in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(1)$$

Let $\zeta_n=1-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)$ and we have:

$$\prod_{n= 2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\prod_{n= 1}^{\infty}(1-\zeta_n)$$

For $n\geq 1$ we have $\dfrac{1}{4n}<\zeta_n$ hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\zeta_n$ diverges. Observe also that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\zeta_n=0$

Now since $0<\zeta_n<1\Rightarrow -\ln (1-\zeta_n)>0$ we may invoke the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-\ln (1-\zeta_n)}{\zeta_n}=1$$

So $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}-\ln (1-\zeta_n)$ diverges and therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\ln (1-\zeta_n)$ also.

It follows that $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\zeta_n)$ diverges.

$$(2)$$

Similar trick here, we now consider $\displaystyle\xi_n=1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right):$

$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} (b_n+1)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\xi_n)$$

For $n\geq 1$ we have $0<\xi_n<\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\xi_n$ converges. Also, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi_n=0$

As before:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-\ln (1-\xi_n)}{\xi_n}=1$$

Hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}\ln(1-\xi_n)$ converges and therefore $\displaystyle\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}(b_n+1)$ converges.